# How to find whether ldap server is up and running?

Tags: ldap

I have currently installed OID (Oracle Internet Directory) and created some roles and users in them. I intend to access them using LDAP commands.

```
$ldapbind -p <port_number> -h <ip> -D "cn=orcladmin"
bind sucessful
$ ldapsearch -h <port_number>  -p <ip> "dc=<name>"
ldap_search: Inappropriate authentication
ldap_search: additional info: Server is Configured to Deny Anonymous Binds
```

Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: What's your actual question? You couldn't have got that message if the server wasn't up.

Comment: Well I intend to access all the online directories using LDAP cmd tools , only the bind cmd seems to work and the rest i keep getting this error . How do i resolve it ?
PS: i am using Oracle Internet Directory

Comment: Err, supply the same authentication that you did to ldapbind? You do understand that these are all separate processes and don't retain any state between their invocations?

Comment: Then how will i have resolve this issue. Is there any other way to solve this ?

Comment: I've just answered that.

Comment: oops , didnt read it carefully , my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your ldapsearch command, add the `-D "cn=orcladmin"` for who you are binding as, `-w "Password"` or `-W` to prompt at run time.  Probably you want a `-b "ou=Base,dc=DNtoSearch"` and then your filter as you have it.

You need to bind each time.